# AWS Load Balancer Failed to Deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer, eksctl

I'm trying to create AWS ALB-Ingress through EKS following the steps in the document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/alb-ingress.html

I was successful till the step 7 in creating the controller:

```
[ec2-user@ip-X-X-X-X eks-cluster]$ kubectl apply -f v2_0_0_full.yaml 
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/targetgroupbindings.elbv2.k8s.aws created 
mutatingwebhookconfiguration.admissionregistration.k8s.io/aws-load-balancer-webhook created 
Warning: kubectl apply should be used on resource created by either kubectl create --save-config or kubectl apply 
serviceaccount/aws-load-balancer-controller configured 
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aws-load-balancer-controller-leader-election-role created 
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aws-load-balancer-controller-role created 
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aws-load-balancer-controller-leader-election-rolebinding created 
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aws-load-balancer-controller-rolebinding created 
service/aws-load-balancer-webhook-service created 
deployment.apps/aws-load-balancer-controller created 
certificate.cert-manager.io/aws-load-balancer-serving-cert created 
issuer.cert-manager.io/aws-load-balancer-selfsigned-issuer created 
validatingwebhookconfiguration.admissionregistration.k8s.io/aws-load-balancer-webhook created
```

However, the controller does NOT get to "Ready" status:

```
[ec2-user@ip-X-X-X-X eks-cluster]$ kubectl get deployment -n kube-system aws-load-balancer-controller
NAME                           READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
aws-load-balancer-controller   0/1     1            0           29m
```

I'm also able to list the pod associated with the controller which also shows NOT READY:

```
[ec2-user@ip-X-X-X-X eks-cluster]$ kubectl get pods -n kube-system
NAME                                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
aws-load-balancer-controller-XXXXXXXXXX-p4l7f   0/1     Pending   0          30m
```

I also can't seem to get its logs in order to try and debug the issue:

```
[ec2-user@ip-X-X-X-X eks-cluster]$ kubectl -n kube-system logs aws-load-balancer-controller-XXXXXXXXXX-p4l7f
[ec2-user@ip-X-X-X-X eks-cluster]$
```

Furthermore, the /var/log directory also does not have any related logs.

Please help me understand why it is not coming to READY state. Also let me know how to enable logging to debug these kind of issues.

Comment: are you sure you updated the cluster name properly? what aws role have you assigned for the controller?

Comment: you can also check deployment status for the error on why it is in "pending" state

Comment: @hjpotter92:
Yes, I have updated the cluster name in the file v2_0_0_full.yaml in one instane as shown below:
```
    spec:
      containers:
        - args:
            - --cluster-name=demo-cluster
```

Comment: @hjpotter92:
Can you please elaborate on how to check the deployment status for the error?

Comment: @hjpotter92:
And, have assigned the role through --attach-policy-arn=arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXXX:policy/demo-policy which was obtained using aws iam create-policy --policy-name demo-policy

Comment: How did you fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer [here](https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-eks-user-guide/pull/245). A faragate deployment requires the region and vpc-id.

```
helm upgrade -i aws-load-balancer-controller eks/aws-load-balancer-controller \
    --set clusterName=<cluster-name> \
    --set serviceAccount.create=false \
    --set region=<region-code> \
    --set vpcId=<vpc-xxxxxxxx>> \
    --set serviceAccount.name=aws-load-balancer-controller \
    -n kube-system
```

Comment: I'm not using Fargate here however the config file I'm using to setup the cluster has the "region" and "vpc-id" parameters.

Comment: I'm not sure it's connected to fargate. Worked fork me regardless ! 

Answer (score 2):

From the [current LB conntroller manifest](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.1.3/docs/install/v2_1_3_full.yaml) I found out that LB controller Pod specification doesn't have `Readiness probe`, only `Liveness probe`. That means that the Pod becomes `Ready` as soon as it pass the Liveness probe:

```
      livenessProbe:
        failureThreshold: 2
        httpGet:
          path: /healthz
          port: 61779
          scheme: HTTP
        initialDelaySeconds: 30
        timeoutSeconds: 10
```

But as we can see in the following output, LB controller's Pod is in `Pending` state:

```
[ec2-user@ip-X-X-X-X eks-cluster]$ kubectl get pods -n kube-system
NAME                                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
aws-load-balancer-controller-XXXXXXXXXX-p4l7f   0/1     Pending   0          30m
```

If Pod stays in `Pending` state, it means that `kube-scheduler` is unable to bind the Pod to a cluster node for whatever reason.

[Kube-scheduler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/kube-scheduler/) is a part of Kubernetes control plain that is responsible for assigning Pods to Nodes.

No Pod logs exist at this phase, because Pod's containers are not started yet.

The most convenient way to check the reason is using the `kubectl describe` command:

```
kubectl describe pod/podname -n namespacename
```

On the bottom of the output there are list of events related to the Pod life cycle. Here is an example for the generic Ubuntu Pod:

```
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----    ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled  37s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/ubuntu to k8s-w1
  Normal  Pulling    25s (x2 over 35s)  kubelet, k8s-w1    Pulling image "ubuntu"
  Normal  Pulled     23s (x2 over 30s)  kubelet, k8s-w1    Successfully pulled image "ubuntu"
  Normal  Created    23s (x2 over 30s)  kubelet, k8s-w1    Created container ubuntu
  Normal  Started    23s (x2 over 29s)  kubelet, k8s-w1    Started container ubuntu
```

`kubectl get events` command can also show the problem. For example:

```
LAST SEEN   TYPE     REASON      OBJECT       MESSAGE
21s         Normal   Scheduled   pod/ubuntu   Successfully assigned default/ubuntu to k8s-w1
9s          Normal   Pulling     pod/ubuntu   Pulling image "ubuntu"
7s          Normal   Pulled      pod/ubuntu   Successfully pulled image "ubuntu"
7s          Normal   Created     pod/ubuntu   Created container ubuntu
7s          Normal   Started     pod/ubuntu   Started container ubuntu
```

or there could be a reason why Scheduler can't assign Pod to a Node:

```
"No nodes are available that match all of the predicates: Insufficient cpu (2), Insufficient memory (2)".
```

In some cases errors could be found in `kube-scheduler` Pod logs in `kube-system` namespace. The logs could be listed using the following command:

```
kubectl logs $(kubectl get pods -l component=kube-scheduler,tier=control-plane -n kube-system -o name) -n kube-system
```

Most common reasons why pod isn't scheduled are the following:

- lack of CPU or memory [resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/) requested by a Pod on the Nodes.
- Pod cannot tolerate [Taints on the Nodes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/)
- Pod have [Affinity/AntiAffinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/) configuration that prevents it from scheduling
- Storage or [other](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/) specific resource (like GPU) requirements in Pod spec cannot be satisfied